# Puppet/Foreman: Nodes are out of sync

Tags: foreman, puppet-agent, puppet-foreman

I got a little problem: I installed `puppet agent` on some nodes. I'm managing the nodes with foreman.

Now some nodes are "out of sync" until I run `puppet agent -t` on the node manually.

The service is running on the nodes:

```
root@node1:/var/log# ps aux | grep puppet
root     10079  0.0  0.0   9240   880 pts/0    R+   17:43   0:00 grep puppet
root     31645  0.0  0.2 196188 36780 ?        Ssl  14:17   0:02 /usr/bin/ruby /usr/bin/puppet agent

root@node1:/var/log# service puppet status
[ ok ] agent is running.
```

What can I do here?

Answer (score 1):

Check two things:

- Puppet agent runinterval `puppet config print runinterval`
- Foreman Puppet 'Out of Sync Interval' `hammer settings list --search 'outofsync_interval'` (Foreman -> Administrator -> Settings -> Puppet -> Out of sync interval)

Make sure the puppet agent checks in more often than the setting in foreman.

As an example:

- in `puppet.conf` I have `runinterval = 6h`
- in `Foreman` I have `outofsync_interval = 400` (just over 6 hours)